# Contact breaking across tilemap while contact is still being made

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an issue that I would really appreciate help with. I am working on a little game designed in tiled. My issue is something like this, say I have a **tile map** platform made out of `16&16 images`. So one is approximately this size 
|*|
and 5 of them side by side will be like
|*||*||*||*||*|.
Now, I have a sprite which runs across it and when ever i move left or right my contact gets spammed. Please look at code and a copy paste of `NSLog` below.(NB Please see the times)

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (collision == (Floor|Player)) {

      NSLog(@"Can jummp");
      onGround=YES;
  }
}
- (void) didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  uint32_t contactTest = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (contactTest == (FLOOR| PLAYER)) {
    // if (contactTest != (floor | player)) {

    NSLog(@"dont jumps");
    onGround = NO;
    /*
    SKPhysicsBody *other = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PCPlayerCategory ?
                            contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA);
    if (other.categoryBitMask & _player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask) {
      // 3
      NSLog(@"dont jumps");
      onGround=NO;
         }
    */
  }
}
```

NSLog :

```
2014-04-29 19:09:53.111 Explorer[4517:a0b] Can jummp
2014-04-29 19:09:53.142 Explorer[4517:a0b] dont jumps
2014-04-29 19:09:53.159 Explorer[4517:a0b] Can jummp
2014-04-29 19:09:53.192 Explorer[4517:a0b] dont jumps
2014-04-29 19:09:53.227 Explorer[4517:a0b] Can jummp
2014-04-29 19:09:53.260 Explorer[4517:a0b] dont jumps
2014-04-29 19:09:53.293 Explorer[4517:a0b] Can jummp
2014-04-29 19:09:53.327 Explorer[4517:a0b] dont jumps
2014-04-29 19:09:53.343 Explorer[4517:a0b] Can jummp
2014-04-29 19:09:53.377 Explorer[4517:a0b] dont jumps
2014-04-29 19:09:53.410 Explorer[4517:a0b] Can jummp
2014-04-29 19:09:53.460 Explorer[4517:a0b] dont jumps
2014-04-29 19:09:53.710 Explorer[4517:a0b] dont jumps
```

This `NSLog` was produced when holding down the left arrow and moving my character left. Because of this "onGround" being set to "NO" when it should be "Yes" it is interfering with the jumping of my character. Is there anyway I can edit my ending contact to that contact is broken when my player actually LEAVES the platform, not the `16*16 image`? 
-Thank you

Tile definition

```
  if([map propertiesForGid:tileGid][@"floor"]) {
    //4
    SKSpriteNode *tile = [layer tileAtCoord:coord];
    tile.name=@"floor";
    tile.physicsBody =
    [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:tile.size];
    tile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = FLOOR;
    tile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =
    PLAYER;
      tile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask=PLAYER;
    tile.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    tile.physicsBody.friction = 0;
      tile.physicsBody.restitution=0;
   }
```

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Your contacts don't appear to be making sense in regards what you are trying to accomplish. You have your didBeginContact (Floor|Player) but your didEndContact (PCPlayerCategory | PCWallCategory). If you are looking to know if your character is jumping, you should set your didEndContact to (Floor|Player). Is there a reason for the way you have it setup now?

Comment: @sangony Sorrry, sigh, i copied the wrong method. the jumping works and it doesnt let me double jump. Issue is everystep calls the end and did begin contact

Comment: If possible, please post a picture of your screen (player, tiles, etc...)

Comment: @sangony Thanks for showing interest in this issue. Looking at the image, I was on the right most tile of that platform and moved to the left.Please not the NSLog generated. Also see how it says "Dont jump" and im sitting on a tile. "Didnt jump is NSloged when i press the red button and im not allowed to jump.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a typo on your part or actual code but do you realize that in your didBeginContact you have (Floor|Player) and in your didEndContact you have (floor|player). Remember that Obj-C is case sensitive.

Comment: @sangony urg, typing error as i type out the method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51712/discussion-between-sangony-and-sleep-paralysis)